# Joomla admin menu

Tags: joomla, components

I wish for you have a good day
can u help me about "admin menu manager" component?
I want to add a new menu to admin menu in back end of joomla that links to a specific module, I do it ,but when I click on it the menu that I created it 
myself this error occurs:

*You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#120).

if I pay for pro version of this component that error will solved?

Comment: Your link must provide a token to get access

Comment: how can I provide a token?

Comment: There is a method in Session class named getToken() try to look from there , your question does not provide informations that anyone can't expect the problem

Comment: G.Mansour Thank You for Your help.